# Изменение класса css после перехода на новую страницу

Tags: css, html5, asp.net-mvc, razor

Здравствуйте. Есть некоторое меню в котором требуется выделять тот пункт на который мы перешли. Например, мы на главной странице и перешли в %раздел_неим%, и ***после*** перехода в этот раздел стиль у этого пункта меню изменился с `class="menu_item"` на `class="menu_item menu_item-active"`

Вопрос: какими способами это можно реализовать? Меню которое берется за основу [здесь](http://omsomsk.ru).

Comment: В примере класс задается на бекенде, вы меню скорее всего циклом выводите, в цикле и подставлять класс.

Comment: в том то и дело что не циклом, слишком простой сайт чтобы таким заморачиваться, есть ли способы через хелперы сделать? я сначала подумал через switch/case так как элементов меню немного но пока не получается

Comment: к сожалению с razor не могу помочь. но могу показать как это сделать на jquery после загрузки страницы

Comment: да пожалуйста, хотя бы так

Comment: Самый простой способ. В контроллере в `ViewBag.Active%раздел_неим%`  записываем `menu_item-active`. В представлении `class="menu_item @ViewBag.Active%раздел_неим%`. Если будет не null, тогда добавиться класс Ваш.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я смог реализовать так:
в контроллере добавляем в методы которые вызываются представления из подменю

```
public ActionResult CertInstall()
    {
        ViewData["MenuItemActive"] = "menu__item-active";
        ViewData["SubMenuActive"] = "menu__item__submenu-active";
        ViewData["CertInstal_SubMenuActive"] = "submenu__item-active";
        return View(ViewData);
    }
```

во view:
блок меню который должен фиксироваться

`<div class="menu__item @ViewData["MenuItemActive"]">`

блок подменю который содержит ссылки

```
<div class="menu__item__submenu @ViewData["SubMenuActive"]">
```

сами ссылки в подменю

```
@Html.ActionLink(~, new { @class = "submenu__item " + @ViewData["CertOrder_SubMenuActive"] })
@Html.ActionLink(~, new { @class = "submenu__item " + @ViewData["CertInstal_SubMenuActive"] })
```

PS. Да это костыль, но пока лучше не смог

полный код меню:

```html
<menu class="menu-wrap">
    @Html.ActionLink("Главная", "Index", "Home", null, new {@class = "menu__item"})
    <div class="menu__item @ViewData["MenuItemActive"]">
        Правила работы
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item__submenu @ViewData["SubMenuActive"]">
        @Html.ActionLink("Заявка на сертификат", "CertOrder", "Home", null, new { @class = "submenu__item " + @ViewData["CertOrder_SubMenuActive"] })
        @Html.ActionLink("Установка сертификата", "CertInstall", "Home", null, new { @class = "submenu__item " + @ViewData["CertInstal_SubMenuActive"] })
     </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Контакты", "Contacts", "Home", null, new { @class = "menu__item" })
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

На примере разметки из вашей ссылки можно сравнивать текущее местоположение и адреса ссылок в меню. В зависимости от того, абсолютные или полные ссылки нужно сравнивать по разным window.location, в примере полный путь.

```js
$().ready(function(){
  console.log(window.location.href);
  $('.menu-wrap .submenu__item').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('href') == window.location.href) {
      var submenu = $(this).closest('.menu__item__submenu');
      $(this).addClass('submenu__item-active');
      submenu.addClass('menu__item__submenu-active');
      submenu.prev().addClass('menu__item-active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.menu__item-active { color: green }
.menu__item__submenu { display: none }
.menu__item__submenu.menu__item__submenu-active { display: block }
.submenu__item-active { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-wrap">

  <div class="menu__item opsans_med">О Фонде</div>
  <div class="menu__item__submenu">
    <a href="https://stacksnippets.net/js" class="submenu__item opsans_med">Информация о руководстве</a>
    <a href="/blog/article/sostav-pravleniya-territorialnogo-fonda-obyazatelnogo-medicinskogo-strahovaniya-omskoy-oblasti" class="submenu__item opsans_med">Состав правления</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu__item opsans_med">О Фонде 2</div>
  <div class="menu__item__submenu">
    <a href="/blog/category/rukovodstvo" class="submenu__item opsans_med">Информация о руководстве</a>
    <a href="/blog/article/sostav-pravleniya-territorialnogo-fonda-obyazatelnogo-medicinskogo-strahovaniya-omskoy-oblasti" class="submenu__item opsans_med">Состав правления</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Да, и еще в примере по ссылке выводится не все дерево меню, только подменю активного раздела, с этим решением необходимо выводить полностью дерево.

Comment: зачем? все логично что отображается подменю активного раздела. странно что не заработало, но все равно спасибо

Comment: @Ackbar, не понял про "зачем", и что не заработало?

Comment: про зачем понял, да, верно, можно не выводить все дерево, достаточно активного

Comment: про "зачем" сглупил, да у меня все дерево так же отображается и сворачивается. не работает - не добавляется класс active и элементы подменю сворачиваются после перехода на новую страницу

Comment: @Ackbar, тут может быть много причин. разная структура, не подключен jquery, не тот путь, не те стили. смотрите через инструменты разработчика браузера, ставьте console.log в нужных местах и смотрите что происходит.

Comment: пути в ссылках я поменял, мне достаточно было вставить js к себе, имена стилей такие же для удобства, но еще раз спасибо. хоть какое то продвижение. Если никто сегодня не ответит больше то помечу ваш ответом